# Use CREATE, SET and add a relationship in Cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a syntax problem with the following query and I think it is impossible to do it like this:

**Adding line breaks for readability, they are not in the actual query.**

```
CREATE (a:USER:TTL {mail: 'a@b.de', fullName: 'example', password: 'spgjwetpjsfj32523rmdcp23r'})
SET a += {
    createdAt : datetime.transaction('Europe/Berlin'),
    ttl : timestamp() + 172800000,
    confirmHash: 697159094 }
-[:HAS_FIRST_ADDRESS]->
(address:ADDRESS:TTL {
    addressStreet: 'ab', addressAddition: 'zusatz', addressCityCode: 12334, addressCity: 'city'})
SET address.createdAt = datetime.transaction('Europe/Berlin'), address.ttl = timestamp() + 172800000
RETURN a
```

This gives me an error:

```
Invalid input ':': expected whitespace, a variable, RelationshipsPattern, an expression or ']'
```

I guess that I cannot use `CREATE (a) SET a+= {prop: 'a'} -[:REL]-> (b) SET b.name = 'ab' RETURN a` in a row, because the query runs well when I **omit the first `SET` part** (the one for the user).

Do I need to set all properties in the parameters for the nodes like `(a {prop: 'a'})`? Is there any way to combine `CREATE` with `SET` and adding a relationship?

I am using Neo4J 4.2.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rewrite your query as such:

```
CREATE (a:USER:TTL {
    mail: 'a@b.de',
    fullName: 'example',
    password: 'spgjwetpjsfj32523rmdcp23r',
    createdAt : datetime.transaction('Europe/Berlin'),
    ttl : timestamp() + 172800000,
    confirmHash: 697159094
})-[:HAS_FIRST_ADDRESS]->(address:ADDRESS:TTL {
    addressStreet: 'ab',
    addressAddition: 'zusatz',
    addressCityCode: 12334,
    addressCity: 'city',
    createdAt: datetime.transaction('Europe/Berlin'),
    ttl: timestamp() + 172800000})
RETURN a
```

If you really need those `SET` clauses, remember that `SET` can only be used for setting properties and labels, not relationships to nodes.
You need `CREATE` (or `MERGE`) to create a relationship between two nodes.

```
CREATE (a:USER:TTL {mail: 'a@b.de', fullName: 'example', password: 'spgjwetpjsfj32523rmdcp23r'})
SET a += {
    createdAt : datetime.transaction('Europe/Berlin'),
    ttl : timestamp() + 172800000,
    confirmHash: 697159094 }
CREATE (address:ADDRESS:TTL {
    addressStreet: 'ab', addressAddition: 'zusatz', addressCityCode: 12334, addressCity: 'city'})
SET address.createdAt = datetime.transaction('Europe/Berlin'), address.ttl = timestamp() + 172800000
CREATE (a)-[:HAS_FIRST_ADDRESS]->(address)
RETURN a
```

Side note: labels usually follow the `PascalCase` case convention, not `UPPERCASE` (`UPPERCASE` is the conventional case for relationship types).

Comment: Ah, the last option is interesting. For now I rewrote the query like you have suggested it in the first example. I think I am using `SET` mainly because there was some hint in the Neo4J docs, which discouraged the reader from using property sets in the node description (`(a:USER)`). But I might be wrong in this point.

Comment: When in doubt, compare your query execution with `EXPLAIN` / `PROFILE`: https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/execution-plans/#execution-plans